# How does this Google API Translator does work?

Tags: c#, json, api, google-api, google-translate

I came across this code here and I would like someone to explain it to me(I would like to use something like this for my compiler).

I would like to ask directly below the question, logically, but I can't add a comment.

1. How does the Google Translate API work in C#? I assume you have to download some Nuget
2. How do you change the language?

Here is the code:

```
var toLanguage = "en";//English
            var fromLanguage = "de";//Deutsch
            var url = $"https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl={fromLanguage}&tl={toLanguage}&dt=t&q={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(word)}";
            var webClient = new WebClient
            {
                Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            };
            var result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
            try
            {
                result = result.Substring(4, result.IndexOf("\"", 4, StringComparison.Ordinal) - 4);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Error";
            }
```

Comment: The code you have there does not use the client library.   I would start here https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v2/csharp  or here https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Translate.V3/latest/index

Comment: You could give a go at writing a comment above each line, saying in plain English what you think each line does then we could see how your code understanding and the code actual differ. This would help inform us as to what teaching to give. In brief, the code makes an HTTP request to a particular url at Google with some parameters to set the word to be translated and the from/to languages, then downloads the response and cuts out a range of characters from the 5th (including) up to the occurrence of the first `"` after the 5th character

Comment: @DaImTo hank you for the link, it is also very interesting.I just wonder if I will have to create my own API in Google Cloud

Comment: Google translate is an api.  You just need to make your own code to connect to that api.    I am just suggesting that you use the Client library created for accessing the api. The code you have their is not using the client library and is making calls directly to the api.

Comment: @DaImTo What if I want to use this code and not the client library?How do I change the language?Do I have to do it directly in the api?I saw that it converts the text to Json

Comment: You just have to send the write body with the api call thats all.   As long as you set that up  properly it should work.   In your example the property for sl is the language your text is currently the tl is the language you want it converted to.    You should go though the api reference if you want to do this yourself.

Comment: @DaImTo I don't understand you.I tried to change languages directly in the program, i.e. fromLanguange="cze"(my native language for example) toLanguange="en". But that just lists the word I entered

Comment: what is the error?  For starters csz isnt on the list [languages](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages) try cs.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you, now I understand everything.